# SQL operations in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

I have a table with columns called:

1. ID (int) (not unique)
2. Type (varchar)
3. Amount (decimal)

For every id there are two 'Type's of records. Called charge and discount with two different amounts.
I want to deduct the discount amount from charge amount and get the final amount for every id.
As an example for Id '2' i may have a charge amount of 200 and a discount amount of 30 so I want my result to be 170 for Id '2'

I can't figure out a clean way to do this.

Comment: when you made this table you should have made discounts negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be absolutely sure there are no other variants of type other than 'charge' and 'discount', then this query should work:

```
select ID, 
sum(case 
      when Type = 'charge' then Amount 
      when Type = 'discount' then Amount*-1
    end) as final_amount
from my_table
group by ID
```

It works by checking first what the type is before deciding what to contribute to the sum. If the value is a `'charge'` then the amount is used, otherwise if the value is a `'discount'` then the amount is negated and will be deducted from the sum.

Assumptions:

1. `'charge'` and `discount` are the only values possible for type
2. Amount is always positive irregardless of type

Comment: what if i want to replace the amount in charge row with the final_amount?

Answer (score 1):

I Have Some Assumptions please this will help you out.

```
Create Table Transactions(ID Int,Type varchar(255),
                    Amount int)

 Insert Into Transactions Values(1,'Charge',10)
 Insert Into Transactions Values(1,'Discount',2)
 Insert Into Transactions Values(2,'Charge',15)
   Insert Into Transactions Values(2,'Discount',3)
  Insert Into Transactions Values(3,'Charge',20)
  Insert Into Transactions Values(3,'Discount',3)
```

Now I created my Query for you solution.

```
Select  T1.ID,T1.Type,T1.Amount-T2.amount  from Transactions T1
 join Transactions T2
 on T1.ID=T2.ID
 and T1.Type<>T2.Type
```

You can filter your answer using where clause like

```
 Select  T1.ID,T1.Type,T1.Amount-T2.amount  from Transactions T1
 join Transactions T2
 on T1.ID=T2.ID
 and T1.Type<>T2.Type
 where T1.Type='Charge'
```

Please Reply.